# Creation date Dropbox account

Tags: dropbox

I want to verify if my Dropbox account was created before the 4<sup>th</sup> of October 2012, to be absolutely sure I'm able to have public folders.

Is it possible to retrieve the creation date of my Dropbox account?

Comment: I don't see anything in my settings. Could you perhaps have saved the "welcome to dropbox" message in your email account?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything within my Dropbox account which tells me exactly when I opened the account.

There are a few things which might help you infer the date, or at least confirm that the account existed before a particular date.

- The [Sharing](https://www.dropbox.com/share) menu shows you items that have been shared with you as well as items shared with you that you've removed, with datetime stamps.
- [Links](https://www.dropbox.com/links/your_links) shows you any links to items you may have created, with datetime stamps
- In the "Account" section of [Settings](https://www.dropbox.com/account#personal), there is a link to "View all space earned" from referrals. Those have general time frames (e.g., 10 months ago, 4 years ago)
- In the "Security" section of [Settings](https://www.dropbox.com/account#security) you can view all of the devices you've connected to your account, with general time frames

[Events](https://www.dropbox.com/events), unfortunately, which would seem to be ideal for this purpose, only seems to go back six months.

I only have a general (free) Dropbox account. I suppose the business or paid accounts may have more information.

Comment: Just like you Al, I'm having a free Dropbox account, mainly for the Public folders option it had. The creation date of the files I added gives me an indication but all the rest is pretty much empty.